# Excel VBA - Perform Operations on visible cells only

Tags: vba, excel

I have a database that has in excess on 200,000 rows. When I was writing a VBA script I had a database of about 20,000 rows in mind so I didn't care whether the database was filtered or not because the VBA script ran quickly. So given the realization that the database is huge and testing the VBA script I was surprised to notice how slowly it ran. So without further to say this is how my code looks like :

```
Set wsDB = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DB")
Dim nameIndex As Long: nameIndex = Application.Match(name, wsDB.Rows(1), 0)
Dim formula As String
   formula = "=IFERROR(AVERAGEIFS(" + GRA(nameIndex) + "," + GRA(dateIndex) + ",R2C," + GRA(cellNameIndex) + ",RC1" + "),"""")"
```

where GRA is a function that returns the address of the range of a column.

```
Private Function GRA(ByRef rngIndex As Long)
   GRA = "DB!" + CStr(Range(Cells(2, rngIndex), Cells(rowNos, rngIndex)).Address(1, 1, xlR1C1, 0, 0))
End Function
```

So given that I now filter the table beforehand how can I adjust my code so that it ignores all the hidden rows and takes into account only what is visible. Of course I am aware that a simple dirty solution would be to simply copy the filter database and paste it in a new sheet but that will affect the performance which is what I'm trying to improve.

Comment: Perhaps `YourRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).FormulaR1C1 = formula` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following function to return a range of only visible cells.

```
Function VisibleCells(Rng As Range) As Variant
Dim R As Range
Dim Arr() As Integer
Dim RNdx As Long
Dim CNdx As Long

If Rng.Areas.Count > 1 Then
    VisibleCells = CVErr(xlErrRef)
    Exit Function
End If

ReDim Arr(1 To Rng.Rows.Count, 1 To Rng.Columns.Count)

For RNdx = 1 To Rng.Rows.Count
    For CNdx = 1 To Rng.Columns.Count
        Set R = Rng(RNdx, CNdx)
        If (R.EntireRow.Hidden = True) Or _ 
                (R.EntireColumn.Hidden = True) Then
            Arr(RNdx, CNdx) = 0 
        Else
            Arr(RNdx, CNdx) = 1
        End If
    Next CNdx
Next RNdx

VisibleCells = Arr

End Function
```

The above code came from http://www.cpearson.com/excel/VisibleCells.aspx.

Normally I would only post code that I write however this does exactly what I was thinking.